# Options to enable HSTS in AWS Application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, hsts

Do we have any options in AWS application load balancer to enable HSTS headers? Find few forum topics, that AWS ALB load balancers doesn't have this as a native option.

We are using AWS ALB SSL terminating load balancer. We configured the load balancer to redirect the unsecured traffic to the secured HTTPS protocol. Now, the requirement is to force the browser to use HTTPS protocol using HSTS header. Any option available in AWS ALB to enable the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on AWS Elastic Load Balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025426/how-to-implement-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-on-aws-elastic-load-balan)

Comment: All of the above are regarding ELB, and this question is about ALB